# AuthFailed at /oauth/complete/github/ Error in Django for social login

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

Authentication failed: The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application.

I have registered i my github account and the callback  url i have set is: http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/github/ and homepage url http://localhost:8000/ but the error is still there. and redirect Url in **settings.py** LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

I have tried many other techniques please help me out

my **urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from developer import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('profileEdit',views.profile_edit_form,name='profileEdit'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('<int:pk>', views.profile_view, name='profileview'),
    path('invites/', views.invites_view, name='invitesview'),
    path('invites/<int:pk>', views.inviter_view, name='inviterview'),
    path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```